# Subgroups of free products of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, finite-groups

Consider the free product $\mathbb{Z}_{3} \star \mathbb{Z}_{3}$. How would one determine the number of subgroups of this product up to isomorphism? It is routine for the case of the product $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \star \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ either by considering the combinations of elements from each group separately or the number of covering spaces of the wedge product of projective spaces. I feel that the easiest way would be to consider the subgroups from the group directly without resorting to topology, but how would one do this?

Comment: You're probably looking for the Kurosh subgroup theorem (which is itself a result from topology or geometric group theory). The number of subgroups up to abstract isomorphism (rather, than, say, the action of $\operatorname{Aut}$) is a bit of an odd thing to look for; what's the context here?

Comment: While self-studying algebraic topology, I was doing a problem that asked me to consider $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \star \mathbb{Z}_{2}$, as the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}P^{2} \wedge \mathbb{R}P^{2}$ where I had to find the covering spaces by looking at the subgroups of the above group. So, I was wondering if this could generalize to higher than cyclic groups of order 2, which would make it easy to find the number of covering spaces of spaces with such fundamental groups.

Comment: As mentioned below, Bass-Serre theory is the general setting for this sort of thing. You might be interested in Serre's "Trees", which covers the basics of the subject. You might also find the related area of HNN-extensions (and similar results from group theory) interesting or useful, but I don't know of a canonical single source for that material.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a generalization, and it is called "Bass-Serre theory". What you learn from that theory is that $\mathbb{Z}_3 * \mathbb{Z}_3$ is a considerably more complicated group than $\mathbb{Z}_2 * \mathbb{Z}_2$. Every infinite subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_2 * \mathbb{Z}_2$ is isomorphic to either itself or to the infinite cyclic group, whereas $\mathbb{Z}_3 * \mathbb{Z}_3$ contains subgroups isomorphic to free groups of any countable rank, as well as many different kinds of free products whose free factors are mixtures of free groups and cyclic groups of order 3.

Comment: So are there infinitely many non-isomorphic subgroups for $\mathbb{Z}_{n} \star \mathbb{Z}_{m}$ for $m,n > 2$? What about the case of $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \star \mathbb{Z}_{3}$?

Comment: Yes, even in $\mathbb{Z}_2 * \mathbb{Z}_3$. Which, by the way, is isomorphic to $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$, a very nice application of Bass-Serre theory that one will find, I believe, in Serre's book "Trees".